# cannot access array from index i-1 through Null Pointer exception

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, nullpointerexception

I'm working on a 2D array. The problem is really simple but I can't figure it out. When I try to access the value from index `array[i-1][j]` it is throwing a Null Pointer exception. While it seems completely legitimate to me to access a index like `array[2-1][2]` . Why it is not working? Is there any logic behind why I can't access array from one back index OR am I doing it wrong please explain.

Code to declare and initialize array:

```
this.Result = new Integer[len][6];
```

Code where Null pointer exception occurring:

```
for(int i=0;i<Result.length;i++) {
    if(i==0){
        Result[i][4]=0;
    }
    else if(Result[i][1]!=null) {
        Result[i][4]=(Result[i-1][2]+Result[i-1][3])+Result[i][2];
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance and please ignore grammar mistakes.

Comment: Which line showing NullPointerExcecption?

Comment: Can you share more code ? What is the declaration of your Result matrix ?

Comment: `private Integer[][] Result;` here it is

Comment: Integer is a class so when you initialize it using class it's default values are null and when you access those null values you will get null pointer exception, use int instead, int will make values of all objects as 0. You can then use them or modify them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an array of the wrapper `Integer` type. This means that the default value for all elements is `null`.

On this line:

```
Result[i][4]=(Result[i-1][2]+Result[i-1][3])+Result[i][2];
```

you are accessing elements that may be uninitialised, which causes the `NullPointerException`.

I suggest you use the primitive `int` type for the array elements to avoid performing operations on `null`s. Another option will be initialise all elements with the value `0` prior to trying to access and perform calculations on them.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like the fields in your array have not been initialized properly. While something like `int[] intArray = new int[length];` initializes all values in the array to zero, `Integer[] integerArray = new Integer[length];` will just fill the array with `null` values.

Are you sure you initialized all fields in your array properly?

Comment: have `int[][] Result;` and `= new int[len][6];

Answer (score 0):

Exception Raised due to `Integer` is a  `Wrapper` Class  in java. So,  this `2-D` array would be filled with `null` not `0`.

if you replace your code

`this.Result = new Integer[len][6];` with `this.Result = new int[len][6];`

error will resolved.